# Which performance issue can I have with the unnecessarily large field data types?

Tags: mysql, database

Let's suppose I create a table named `student` and here is the part of the query.

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    department VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
...
```

The `department` field can contain up to 500 characters, but in reality it's not likely for a record to take the entire length ('political science' is 17 characters long and 'computer engineering' takes 20 characters). But what I wonder is, which performance issue might occur if I leave the field as it is and execute queries?

Comment: Why not having `department` in different table and have this field as foreign key in `student` table? it will also reduce the redundant data.

Comment: It's VARCHAR, so it's costing you 1 byte. Don't worry about it.

Comment: When indexing, note that you can index just the first few characters of a string. The 5.7 manual entry was the first one I found... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html#create-index-column-prefixes

Comment: That said, you should of course store department separately, and store the department is here, as mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a separate table for the department?
The performance will be better when you query for all students in a department.